# How stop depth join hibernate in a query?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

Hi I have this 3 Class:

```
public class A{

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    private B b;

        .....
}

public class B{

    @OneToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    private C c;

        .....
}

public class C{
        .....
}
```

I have a `findById(id)` on my `A` class, and hibernate do a join to `B` class, and the it do another join to `C` class.

But I don't need to get C class' fields, so can I do??

Thank you

Comment: @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) if you have your field marked as nullable=true then hibernate will do an extra join anyway but this is a different problem that occurs only for 1to1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved as suggested:

I add `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` because my filed isn't mandatory..

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set `max_fetch_depth` hibernate property to a properly value.

From hibernate documentation:

Sets a maximum "depth" for the outer join fetch tree for single-ended associations (one-to-one, many-to-one). A 0 disables default outer join fetching.
e.g. recommended values between 0 and 3.

But keep in mind that this will affect your entire project.